# iOS Broadcast Extension using replaykit is not Working

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, replaykit

hi i am trying to making broadcasting app which support screen broadcast feature like Mobcrush.

So i try to implement Broadcast App Extension that was introduced at WWDC, but my Demo App Doesn't work Well. My Demo App Just Doesn't Broadcast And Just Show Me a Error Alert Which Says "Live Broadcast to MYDemoApp has stopped due to: (null)"

Here Are The Things What I Did On Demo App

Implementing App Extension(BroadCast Extension. Which Makes SampleHandler, BroadcastSetupViewController)

Pod Install And Copied The Codes That I Didn't Write From Other Developer's Demo App (HaishinKit) (https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift)

Put RTMP URL String in userDidFinishSetup() in BroadcastSetupViewController (This App is Demo, So i Just Put My Own RTMP Address And Stream Key)

Plus, I Think this is Not RTMP URL Issue. because i already did Camera(Front, Rear) Broadcast Test With That URL(Not an App Extension. Just in the Simple ViewController).

Could you Tell Me A Hint? Any Feedback Would Be Appreciated!

Thank For You Reading My First Question About Coding.

Comment: Can you please post some code, it looks to be that you are passing a null reference to something but without some code its hard to tell what. If you are not sure where your app is breaking, try adding break points to different functions inside your application and stepping through until it crashes.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Make sure in the upload extension's info.plist the NSExtensionPointIdentifier is com.app.broadcast-services-upload Also the RPBroadcastProcessMode should be RPBroadcastProcessModeSampleBuffer